# Can't convert JSONArray into a list (Kotlin)

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, gson

This is my string:

```
{"array":[{"message":"test1","name":"test2","creation":"test3"},{"message":"test1","name":"test2","creation":"test3"}]}
```

And I want it get that array into a list of object in Kotlin app for Android.
I tried to do it using two examples from this site... So here is my code (res = that string):

```
val gson = Gson()
val obj = gson.fromJson(res, JsonObject::class.java)
val arr = obj.getAsJsonArray("array")

println(arr.toString())
val list1 : List<JThread> = gson.fromJson(arr, object : TypeToken<List<JThread>>() {}.type)
val list2 = gson.fromJson(arr, Array<JThread>::class.java).asList()

for (x in list1){
   println(x.message)
}
for (x in list2){
   println(x.message)
}
```

However I'm only getting null in x.message. I don't know what can go wrong.
I also tried changing arr to arr.toString() everywhere and that didn't work either.

Also JThread is:

```
object JThread {
var message: String? = null
var name: String? = null
var creation: String? = null }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import com.google.gson.Gson

data class Array(
    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String,
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("creation")
    var creation: String
)

data class Example(
    @SerializedName("array")
    var array: List<Array>? = null
)

private fun fromJson(json:String):Example{
    return Gson().fromJson<Example>(json, Example::class.java)
}
```

PS: I made it with this site:http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I changed this line "var array: List<Array>? = null" to "var array: Array<JThread>? = null" and it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "JSON to Kotlin class " plugin also do the conversion work perfectly. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-

Comment: Cool, will try it. Thanks for tge advice!

Answer (score 6):

This can be done without GSON or any other third party library:

```
@Throws(JSONException::class)
fun JSONObject.toMap(): Map<String, Any> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    val keysItr: Iterator<String> = this.keys()
    while (keysItr.hasNext()) {
        val key = keysItr.next()
        var value: Any = this.get(key)
        when (value) {
            is JSONArray -> value = value.toList()
            is JSONObject -> value = value.toMap()
        }
        map[key] = value
    }
    return map
}

@Throws(JSONException::class)
fun JSONArray.toList(): List<Any> {
    val list = mutableListOf<Any>()
    for (i in 0 until this.length()) {
        var value: Any = this[i]
        when (value) {
            is JSONArray -> value = value.toList()
            is JSONObject -> value = value.toMap()
        }
        list.add(value)
    }
    return list
}
```

Usage to convert JSONArray to List:

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonArrStr)
val list = jsonArray.toList()
```

Usage to convert JSONObject to Map:

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonObjStr)
val map = jsonObject.toMap()
```

More info is [here](https://github.com/michaelavoyan/JSONExtentions/blob/main/JSONExtentions.kt)